# find a Xor b equals to n.can you suggest me the efficient way of finding xor value

Tags: algorithm

let there is two number a and b such that a^b is n.I have given n value I need to find a and b.
**EXAMPLE**

```
n=5
a=1 b=4 and a^b=5
similarly  a=9  b=12
please help to find this.'
```

Comment: Pick any value for a, and b is a^n.

Answer (score 1):

Write both numbers in binary form and compute the `XOR` bit-by-bit:

```
a =  9     1 0 0 1
b = 12     1 1 0 0

a ^ b = n  0 1 0 1    decimal 5

a ^ n = b  1 1 0 0

b ^ n = a  1 0 0 1
```

In general terms:

```
a          w  x  y  z

b          w !x  y !z

n          0  1  0  1
```

You can take an arbitrary `a`, invert two bits as shown to get `b` such that `a ^ b = 5`.

Comment: we have only n=5.we have to find a and b such that a^b=n.we are not give a and b.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no constrain on value of **a** and **b** then **a** can be 0 and **b** is equal to **n** (because **xor** of any number with zero is equal to same number).

If **0<a,b<n** then you can iterate from 1 to n , and assign that value to **a** ,then value of **b** will be **n^a** check if **b** is less than **n** or not , if it is then print **a** and **b**

```
int a,b,n;
a=-1;
b=-1;
cin>>n;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    b=i^n;
    if((b>0) && (b<=n))
    {
        a=i;
        break;
    }
}
cout<<a<<" "<<b;
```

Comment: we are given only n value like n=5 and we have to find a and b such that a^b=n and 0<a,b<=n